# Unfortunately android app has stopped: But found no error in project

Tags: android

I am just a beginner in android programming, currently I am creating a simple project in android. But I am facing lot of errors in that. I have few doubts to ask:

1) Whenever I create a project its creating a two layout *activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml* I know what is fragment but I am little confused which one to use...! some say just use *fragment_main.xml* to design all the activity. is it correct? or I need to use *activity_main* also?

2) I created a app which first display the flash screen and then it goes to activity but when I run the app it showing unfortunately the app had stopped and the code is

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}}
```

AboutUs:

```
public class AboutUs extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView tv_au1;
TextView tv_woff;
Button btn_go;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

    tv_au1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv_woff=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btn_go=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_go.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about_us, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent go_create_note = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(go_create_note);

}}
```

I don't have any errors in my project, and my logcat is:

```
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.example.notedip.AboutUs.onCreate(AboutUs.java:32)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-08 13:00:05.790: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  ... 11 more
```

Can anyone explain this? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The error is a Null Pointer Exception on line 32 in `AboutUs` activity. Could you please say which line it is? I suspect that you create the views inside `fragment_about_us` and not `activity_about_us`, is it the case?

Comment: yes I made all the design(view) in *fragment_about_us* and not in *activity_about_us*. If I am wrong please tell me in which I need to do all the design and when I need to use *fragment_about_us (layout)*

Comment: @iFido2020 make the changes mentioned in my post

Comment: Copy all the code from fragment_about to activity_about_us.xml which is the simplest solution.. @iFido2020

Comment: @Lal I tried but its not working.

Comment: Still the same error???

Comment: @lal yes, Still same error only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the views belong to `fragment_about_us.xml` in which case you need to initialize views in Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us,
            container, false);
    tv_au1=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv_woff=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btn_go=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_go.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}
```

Change this

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
```

to

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
```

Then move the below to fragment class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent go_create_note = new Intent(getActivity(), Dashboard.class);
startActivity(go_create_note);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) can u please tell me which one to prefer always? fragment_main.xml or activity_main.xml?

Comment: use fragments and it depends on what you want activity or fragments